# ERROR Unexpected end of JSON , input Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting two errors when I submit form in edit mode.

**Unexpected end of JSON**

**input Unexpected end of JSON input**

Update works fine and save values in database just I can see this message in console and route redirect after submit doesn't work. This is code service and components file.

**threat.service.ts**

```
updateThreat(threat: Threat): Observable<Threat> {
    var requestOptions = this.authService.requestOptionsWithToken();
    return this.http.put(this.serviceUrl + 'api/threat', threat, requestOptions)
        .map(extractData)
        .catch(handleError);
}

public extractData(res: any) {
    return res.json() || [];
}

public handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

**add-edit-threat-component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { Threat } from '../../../../models/threat.model';
import { ThreatService } from '../../../../services/threat.service';
import { ThreatComponent } from '../threat/threat.component';

@Component({
selector: 'app-add-edit-threat',
templateUrl: './add-edit-threat.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./add-edit-threat.component.css']
})

export class AddEditThreatComponent implements OnInit {

threatCategories: any[];
threatForm: FormGroup;

id: number;
editMode: boolean = false;

typeOfThreat = [
    { value: 1, name: 'Security' },
    { value: 2, name: 'Safety' }
];

originOfThreat = [
    { value: 1, name: 'Internal' },
    { value: 2, name: 'External' },
    { value: 3, name: 'Both' }
];

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private threatService: ThreatService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    if (this.route.snapshot.params["id"]) {
        this.id = +this.route.snapshot.params["id"];
    }

    this.threatForm = this.fb.group({
        threatId: 0, 
        name: ['', [Validators.required]],
        category: ['', [Validators.required]],
        description: [''],
        internalExternal: [1, Validators.required],
        securitySafety: [3, Validators.required],
        avoidRisk: [false],
        shareRisk: [false],
        reduceRisk: [false],
        acceptRisk: [false],
        confidenciality: [false],
        integrity: [false],
        availability: [false],
        authenticity: [false],
    })
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.onGetThreatsCategory();

    if (this.id > 0) {
        this.editMode = true;
        this.threatService.getThreat(this.id)
            .subscribe(data => this.threatForm.patchValue(data))
    }
}

onGetThreatsCategory() {
    this.threatService.getThreatCategory()
        .subscribe(
        response => {
            this.threatCategories = response.items;
        });
}

onSubmit() {
    if (!this.threatForm.valid) {
        return
    }

    if (!this.editMode) {
        this.threatService.createThreat(this.threatForm.value)
            .subscribe((data) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/threat']);
                console.log(this.threatForm);
            })
    }
    else if (this.editMode) {
        this.threatService.updateThreat(this.threatForm.value)
            .subscribe((data) => {
                this.router.navigate(['/threat']);
                console.log(this.threatForm);
            })
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Sounds like you're endpoint is returning bad data for PUT requests. You also have some issues that are unrelated. Your error-handling is problematic (never pass references to unbound methods, a union type that includes `any` is always just `any`, `instanceof` tests are bad design in JavaScript especially when deserializing, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

When I changed function

```
public extractData(res: any) {
return res.json() || [];
}
```

with

```
.map((response: Response) => response)
```

in updateThreat function erros have disappeared and everything works well.

```
updateThreat(threat: Threat): Observable<Threat> {
    var requestOptions = this.authService.requestOptionsWithToken();
    return this.http.put(this.serviceUrl + 'api/threat', threat, requestOptions)
        .map((response: Response) => response)
        .catch(this.dataService.handleError);
}
```